# Knowing if an account had tweeted

Tags: twitter

Background info:
My website has an account system and we wanted to give the accounts "reward points" everytime they tweeted / facebook share.

For facebook share, we are able to track which account had shared by using the redirect_uri and redirect them back to our site (with the specified url) and noting it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Is there such thing on twitter as well? I had been trying to find real hard but i can't find a way for me to inform my system that a certain account had tweeted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the basic objects in the Twitter API is the User object, which gives you a decent amount of information about the user in question.  Once of the properties of the User object is called "status", which is a Tweet object, which is the user's most recent tweet.

So, in your application, you could store the unique identifier and date/time of the user's last tweet.  Then at an interval of your choosing, you could get the information about the user and see if the ID of their most recent tweet matches what you have in your database.  If it does not match, then the user has posted a new tweet.

[Twitter API documentation of the User object](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/users)

[Twitter API documenation of the Tweet object](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets)